# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/projects/4103"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have re-written an application from an older version of Rails v3.2 to the current version of Rails v6.1.4.1.

I have everything working now except a datalogger upload function.  The upload starts, progress bars build but it never makes it to the controller create action because of this POST error I am getting.  What is confusing is the routes is the same routes file that is currently working on the older version with the exception of the via.  I did have to add a bunch of via: [:get, :post] statements to the routes that started with match as apparently the newer version of Rails requires it.

Here is the relative portion of the routes file:

```
resources :projects do
    collection do
      post 'search' => 'projects#index', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
      get 'search', action: 'index'
    end

    match 'prepare', to: 'projects#prepare', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'verify', to: 'projects#verify', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'review', to: 'projects#review', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'certification_letter', to: 'projects#certification_letter', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'certification_publication', to: 'projects#certification_publication', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'print', to: 'projects#print', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'dataloggers/v:version', to: 'dataloggers#create', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'stats', to: 'projects#stats', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'logs', to: 'audits#logs', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'datalogger_bypass', to: 'dataloggers#bypass', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'soft_destroy', to: 'projects#soft_destroy', via: [:get, :post]

    resources :dataloggers do
      match 'report', to: 'dataloggers#report', via: [:get, :post]
    end
  end
```

Here is the error from the console:

```
Started POST "/projects/4103" for ::1 at 2021-11-23 10:23:21 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/projects/4103"):
```

Here is what SHOULD be taking place. *This is a different project number but the function is the same.
I have the console dump from the original version running on Heroku and at this exact point it should be doing this: (I just included the beginning part not the paperclip entries and the S3 entries)

```
2021-11-22T22:36:41.176564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/projects/4199/dataloggers?user_id=1" host=des.emissionsgateway.com request_id=cf8466a2-3cb4-4ad2-ab38-1a2e7ca4c16e fwd="66.189.160.205" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=1361 protocol=http
2021-11-22T22:36:41.097213+00:00 app[web.1]: Cache read: http://des.emissionsgateway.com/projects/4199/dataloggers?user_id=1
2021-11-22T22:36:41.098499+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/projects/4199/dataloggers?user_id=1" for 66.189.160.205 at 2021-11-22 22:36:41 +0000
2021-11-22T22:36:41.103209+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DataloggersController#create as */*
```

Here is the Relevant Rails routes from Heroku:

```
  project_dataloggers GET      /projects/:project_id/dataloggers(.:format)                       dataloggers#index
                                  POST     /projects/:project_id/dataloggers(.:format)                       dataloggers#create
```

Here is the same info from my new app:

```
project_dataloggers_path    GET /projects/:project_id/dataloggers(.:format) 
dataloggers#index

POST    /projects/:project_id/dataloggers(.:format) 
dataloggers#create
```

What I need to know is how to get that POST to match to something.  I have tried every combination I can think of even going as far as just trying to match the exact project just as a test IE:

```
match '/projects/4103', to: 'dataloggers#create', via: :post
```

It gives me the very same error and I just don't understand why it is not matching especially when I give it the exact information.

I didn't post the controller because it never gets to the controller, if I can get the route to match I believe it would then get to the datalogger_controller.rb file.  I have logger.debug commands in the create action to show me what is going on but it never makes it there because of this POST error.

Here is the error that comes up in the browser:
[image]

The steps I take is I go to add the file, it starts the upload, displays the error in the console about the POST error. The end.

If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful.  I did try just taking the matches out of the file since there is a resources: dataloggers but that also did not work.

If anyone wants me to post more information let me know what you want to see and I will add it.  I tried to keep it just to the relevant sections of code as far as I know them.

Thank You,
Scott

Comment: I don't really think the error here is with the routes - even if making everything accessible via GET and POST is absolutely horrendous.  Rather its whatever uploader you're using thats broken and is producing a bad URL.

Comment: Ok, thank you Max!, I will check that out.  Once I get this issue figured out I will also go back over and figure out which exact routes each of the items need for the match statements I just did that to get the app up and working and had planned to come back to that later.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure it was the routes issue, but I knew I had to add the via statement and wasn't sure if that was causing a problem or if they changed something else on newer Rails.  So it helps me to know that I need to look at other items.  Thanks again Max!